# Applying a radial gradient to a shape?

Tags: excel, vba, gradient, shapes, radial-gradients

I want to apply a **radial** gradient to a Shape object via the TwoColorGradient method.

It appears the MsoGradientStyle enum doesn't have an option for a radial gradient.

```
With Feuil6.Shapes("GONDOLE_1").Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .TwoColorGradient msoGradientFromCenter, 1
    .GradientStops(1).Position = 0
    .GradientStops(1).Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
    .GradientStops(1).Transparency = 0
    .GradientStops(2).Position = 0
    .GradientStops(2).Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
    .GradientStops(2).Transparency = 0
    .GradientStops.Insert2 RGB(22, 56, 187), 0.46, 0, 3, -0.4
    .RotateWithObject = msoTrue
End With
```

The `msoGradientFromCenter` is the closest I've gotten to a true radial gradient, but it's not really radial.

The macro recorder is useless for testing on shapes, so I'm at a standstill.

I'm using Excel 2016.

How do I apply a true radial gradient using VBA code?

Comment: I just tried but it seems that setting the radial gradient is not possible via VBA PowerPoint. The only solution left is to change directly the PPTX file (`<a:path path="circle">` versus `<a:path path="rect">`). Source: [this question in Microsoft forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3601fd94-ffc8-4753-97b4-5e52d56fd0d4/the-radial-gradient-in-powerpoint).